# Extract elements from data column (String) before and after character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract a character before and after certain characters in a string, most of these are in a pandas dataframe column.

Basically I want to take from my principal dataframe and merge together is from my columns 'Strain' and 'Region' taking the following items:

i) Original Strain: *Streptomyces_sp_QL40_O*

ii) Original Region: *Region&nbsp1.1*

Extract:

1. The string after the second underscore *Ex:* **QL40**
2. The first number before the '.' *Ex:* nbsp.**1**
3. The second number after the '.' *Ex:* .**1**
4. The string region before the '&' character
5. Add two 0's after string 'region' if digit is less than 10 and one 0 if digit is more than ten.

**Desired Output**: *QL40_1.region001*

**Example below**

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [['Streptomyces_sp_QL40_O', 'Region&nbsp1.1'], ['Streptomyces_sp_QL40_O', 'Region&nbsp2.2'], ['Streptomyces_sp_QL40_O', 'Region&nbsp2.1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Strain', 'Region'])

print(df)

region_list = ['QL40_1.region001', 'QL40_2.region002', 'QL40_3.region001']
```

I started with something like this:

```
df['BGC Region'] = df['Strain'].str.split('_').str[2]
print('DataFrame Modified')
df['BGC Region'] = df['BGC Region'].astype(str) + '_' 
df['Region No'] = df['Region'].str.split('.').str[1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not really sure if this is what you want, but it does the work:

```py
regions = []
for i in df['Region'].str.split('.').str[0]:
    regions.append(''.join([d for d in i if d.isdigit()]))

df['BGC Region'] = df['Strain'].str.split('_').str[2] + '_' + regions + '.region'

region_number = df['Region'].str.split('.').str[1]
for i, rn in enumerate(region_number):
    if int(rn) < 10:
        df['BGC Region'][i] += '00' + rn
    elif int(rn) < 100:
        df['BGC Region'][i] += '0' + rn
```

Comment: thanks for your approach on this! However in the second for loop the second integer (the one after the '.' character) and the 0's are not being added after region and between the region number: example (MBT8_1.region **#**)

Comment: Can you provide this example in the pair format like `'Streptomyces_sp_xxxx', 'Region&nbspx.x'`

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to:

- concatenate your 2 columns (inserting a '_' between them),
- call `str.extract` to extract the parts of interest, specified with
  a regex pattern with proper named capturing groups,
- for each row, merge these parts, adding the required number of zeroes.

To implement it, start with creating of an intermediate DataFrame:

```
df2 = (df.Strain + '_' + df.Region).str.extract(
    r'(?:[^_]+_){2}(?P<QL>[^_]+)_[^_]+_(?P<Rg>[^&]+)\D+(?P<D1>\d)\.(?P<D2>\d)')
```

The result, for your data, is:

```
     QL      Rg D1 D2
0  QL40  Region  1  1
1  QL40  Region  2  2
2  QL40  Region  2  1
```

Then define a merging function, to be applied for each row from *df2*:

```
def mrg(row):
    rg = row.Rg + '0'
    if len(rg) < 11:
        rg += '0'
    return row.QL + '_' + row.D1 + '.' + rg + row.D2
```

And to get the final result, run:

```
region_list = df2.apply(mrg, axis=1).tolist()
```

The result is:

```
['QL40_1.Region001', 'QL40_2.Region002', 'QL40_2.Region001']
```

Comment: thanks for following up with this! :) Question: For the first snippet of code when creating an intermediate dataframe, a majority of the rows are created with _NaN_ values and a second question, the row variable for the mrg function can just be extracted directly from the original dataframe correct?

Comment: For your sample data every row in the intermediate DataFrame is free of any *NaN* values.
Apparently you didn't provide representative data.
Maybe your data (at least the rows of interest) do not contain the required fields
(the content to be matched by capturing groups).
Inspect what is wrong with the "failed" rows and change the regex in such a way it matches also these cases.