# Create Variable of Extracted Substring Before and After Character

Tags: python, pandas

In a data table, I have a variable `'RESULT'` with a ton of text that looks like this:

```
Transfer Handoff Entered On:  07/25/2021 2:45 EDT    Performed On:  07/25/2021 2:45 EDT by 
LAST, FIRST RN  Handoff   Clinician Relationship to Patient :   Nurse   
Clinician Receiving Report :   Handoff Transfer Type :   Intra-hospital   Sending Unit :   EMTC   Date, Time Report Given :   07/25/2021 2:45 EDT   
Receiving Unit :   4 Main Access   Intrahospital Transfer Mode :   Wheelchair   Transfer 
Notifications :   Father   Transfer Note :   report given via IPASS method
```

I want to extract the text after 'Receiving Unit :' and before 'Intrahospital' to create its own separate column resulting in a database that looks like this:

```
PT_FIN       RESULT                              RECEIVING_UNIT
124324        *All of the text from above*        4 Main Access
```

I've done a little research and found a number of similar posts but not quite sure on how to get the ball rolling on developing some code.

[Extract elements from data column (String) before and after character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606586/extract-elements-from-data-column-string-before-and-after-character)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pandas function [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), as follows:

```
df['RECEIVING_UNIT'] = df['RESULT'].str.extract(r'Receiving Unit\s*:(.*?)\s*Intrahospital')
```

**Demo**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'RESULT': ['Receiving Unit :   4 Main Access   Intrahospital Transfer Mode :   Wheelchair   Transfer ']})

df['RECEIVING_UNIT'] = df['RESULT'].str.extract(r'Receiving Unit\s*:(.*?)\s*Intrahospital')

print(df)

                                                                                      RESULT    RECEIVING_UNIT
0  Receiving Unit :   4 Main Access   Intrahospital Transfer Mode :   Wheelchair   Transfer      4 Main Access
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to match & extract the in-between text.

```
import re
def get_text(txt):
    mytxt = re.search(r'Receiving Unit \:(.*?)Intrahospital Transfer Mode', txt).group(1)
    return mytxt

df['RECEIVING_UNIT'] = [get_text(x) for x in df['RESULT']]
```

if your df is big, then SeaBean's solution may be more efficient.